# Does not assign a value to a global variable

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to set value by Ajax request, and it's not working!
This is what I doing:

```
function getStores()
{
    var stores;

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '/handlers/AccountHandler.php?method=list',
        success: function(response, opts)
        {
            stores = Ext.JSON.decode( response.responseText );
        }
    });

    return stores; // null || undefined
}
```

Comment: Ext.Ajax.request is asynchronous - stores wont be updated until after you `return stores`

Comment: The duplicate question is using jQuery, but the same solution